# SwiftUI Text seems dependant on Image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I Have the following code, displaying the featured image of an article and the title of the article. However, when the Image object is present, the Text object does not become multiline, does not truncate etc.

When I comment out the Image object however, the text renders exactly as I want it to.

Is this intended behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

```
import SwiftUI

struct articleDetail: View {

    var article : News

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: article.image ?? Data()) ?? UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "protoLogo"))
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(height: 200)
                .clipped()
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

            Text(article.title!)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .lineSpacing(10)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .truncationMode(.head)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you expected like the following demo

[image: demo]

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: article.image ?? Data()) ?? UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "protoLogo"))
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(height: 200)
            .clipped()
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())

        Text(article.title!)
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

*Note: also removed all unneeded/default modifiers*